# how the other core call is realized

Tags: multithreading, x86, 64-bit, cpu, processor

the program is in the memory and first prosesor executes 
it, then there is a call to a function which is said to
be executed on the other core - how the first core sends
the call adres to the other core ? Is there some communication
mechanism between the cores other than the shared ram for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's like this.  Threads cannot be called, only signaled, and function are not, in general, tied to threads - several threads on several cores may be executing the same function/code.

That said, there is certainly an inter-processor driver that can communicate between cores.  This is essential to allow threads to be allocated to cores and also to allow the OS to stop threads when a process terminates.

When inter-core comms is required, the producer thread stores data in shared memory and signals the other core by asserting a hardware-interrupt, so forcing the 'target' core to enter the OS and handle the signaled data.

Essentially, none of this is even remotely trivial and, if you wish to know more/have your brain bent out of shape, look at the scheduler/dispatcher code for linux or sign your life away with M$.

Comment: dont you know maybe some text about hardware side of this things (those intercore interrupts mentioned - how it works - I know how the interrupts work on one core system but not on more core system (the os side things are less interesting to me than knowing how it worx in hardware)